# fabric: Stacktrace on error?

Tags: stack-trace, fabric

If a `fabric` command fails, we get the below output.

But it would be very good for debugging to get a stacktrace.

I looked at `fab --help` and could not find an answer.

Here is our current output:

```
[remote-host] out: 


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Requested: ...
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "source /localhome/foo_eins_dtg/bin/activate && ...

Aborting.
Disconnecting from foo_eins_dtg@remote-host... done.
Disconnecting from root@remote-host... done.
```

How to get a stacktrace if the fabric command failes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now it is not possible. I asked on the mailing list.

bitprophet (the author) opened a ticket for the feature request:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1200